# how to make scroll bars to work on panel when panel size is greater than frame size

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane

[image: unseen content still left and scroll bars wont work properly]

Image: unseen content still left and scroll bars wont work properly

i am creating many drop down lists(actual no of lists is determined at run time as value of some variable n) as shown into the pane and when they are
too many i want scroll bars to do the job. But scroll bars wont work.
this is what i basically did.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

then added all labels,buttons and dropdown lists into this panel.
then added panel to JScrollPane

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel,/*constants*/);
```

then added this scrollPane into frame

```
dest_frame.add(scrollPane);
```

How to make them work?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"How to make them work?"* From the three lines of code supplied, all I can suggest is - don't use `null` layouts. If that's not the case, see the comment about the MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: that actually helped.. thanx..